# noty not working on init

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

Im **complete noob** to Javascript, but very keen to learn more.

I have a flex application, that I am messing with the HTML wrapper, to try and pop up an alert to point user to help.

I found a great jQuery plugin called [noty](http://needim.github.com/noty/), that emulates the header alerts that you also see in SE-sites.

```
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="custom/css/jquery.noty.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="swfobject.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" 
        src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="custom/js/jquery.noty.js"></script>         
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
// basic alert
//if (!confirm("Yo.\n\nAccept?"))
//    window.location.href = "custom/rejected.htm";

noty({text: 'yo!'});
</script>

</head>
```

Not getting any errors in firebug, but alert is not firing either.
I know its something basic, and will need some additional logic to tell it to fire at runtime, right?

What have I done wrong or what code am I missing?

Thanks

Full code [here.](http://pastebin.com/Ys2WxJGE)  Let me know via comments if you need more info.

Comment: Can you recheck your code again? In my case, it worked. 
see: http://jsfiddle.net/qLGfe/
The only thing I changed that I removed remaining code that lies below your noty() call. Try commenting that code locally and check.

Comment: I believe fiddles use document ready behind the scenes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know Noty, but if it's a visual effect than it certainly depends on the DOM being scriptable and nodes being rendered. What's happening is that noty is firing before the DOM is scriptable.

A core concept in jQuery is using the "document ready" function. Consider it a "page is built, now I can manipulate it" function. People like to be fancy and use shortcut syntax (there are a few variations), but I prefer explicit and obvious syntax, so I use the standard:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Code here executes when DOM is scriptable
});
```

Just put the noty code inside there and it should work, I'm guessing:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  noty({text: 'yo!'});
});
```